# jQuery dataTables - JSON input not displaying on page

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

My JSON output from controller reads like this:

```js
{"subscribers":"[{\"code\":\"Code1\",\"name\":\"Name1\",\"id\":539,\"companyId\":\"CD1\",\"acctNum\":\"Dell\"},{\"code\":\"Code2\",\"name\":\"Name2\",\"id\":540,\"companyId\":\"CD2\",\"acctNum\":\"Dell1\"}]"}
```

It is the output variable "**data**" from the controller 'three.htm' :

```js
$("#getName").click(function() {
     $.getJSON("three.htm", function(data) {
         })
         .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
         var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
         alert(err);
         console.log( "Request Failed: " + err);
         })
         .success(function(data){
             console.log("loadDataTable >>  "+JSON.stringify(data));
             loadDataTable(data);
         })
 });

 function loadDataTable(data){
     $("#recentSubscribers").dataTable().fnDestroy(); 
     var oTable = $('#recentSubscribers').dataTable({
         "aaData" : data,
         "processing": true,
        "aoColumns" : [
           {"mData" : "code" },
          { "mData" : "name" },
          { "mData" : "id" },
          {"mData" : "companyId" },
          {"mData" : "acctNum" }
           ]
        });
     }
```

However, the datatable isn't showing any results.

Pretty much stuck here after trying many approaches. Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is basically just an object with one item, `subscribers`, holding a long string. You need to parse that string to JSON before it can be inserted to dataTables :

```js
...
"aaData" : JSON.parse(data.subscribers),
...
```

Your code working here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/x5n94dqv/**

Comment: Thank you! Worked so well like a charm :) Was stuck on this small part for pretty long time.